How to balance what the accepted wisdom demands vs. what the conscience demands in advising young trainees?
This post is focused on the life sciences. Encouraging students to pursue a career in biomedical research is taken as indisputably the right thing to do. For example see, this page from the U.S. National Institute of General Medical Sciences.
Yet, a more sober evaluation shows that such career path is fraught with some serious shortcomings that are usually minimized or even ignored. For example see this article, not to mention ridiculous funding “success” rates.
The question is: with the rosy picture of biomedical research career path typically painted - should one go with the conventional wisdom and encourage young people along that path, or should one go with what the conscience demands and warn these same young people to beware? Or perhaps there’s a third alternative.

How is it any different from career advice in pretty much every profession?

@JonCuster I would think there’s a lot of overlap. However I opted to focus on the science area I’m experienced in. (Math field seems to be significantly different).

Different aims for different groups. The NIH wants to ensure a large crop of budding researchers to compete, best of the best sort of thing. Educators have a different aim: To train those selecting that path, ideally making them aware of the funnel—and options—ahead.

Every career path is fraught with some serious shortcomings that are usually minimized or even ignored. Do you have something better to recommend to them?

@MisterMiyagi True. Except that the discrepancy between the myth and the reality of the biomedical research field is particularly pronounced.

@JonCuster Careers in most professions are not characterized by extreme funnel of academia, where you either keep progressing up the ladder or have to switch careers. In most career paths you can simply stall out and stay at your current level.

@TimRias Nicely articulated.

I wouldn't accept the premise that these shortcomings are "minimized or even ignored." In my circles, there's lots of discussion about science as a career path. Just look at academic Bluesky, or even posts here. I linked up your bare links, but let me suggest your second-to-last sentence is a bit tortured.

@AzorAhai-him- Thank you for linking up. Respectfully, I have a very different view than yours. It's not that shortcomings are never discussed. They are. But on balance, such shortcoming are indisputably minimized compared to their actual magnitude. And it's not about discussions in circles. It's about giving an accurate view in public of the field to young people possibly contemplating such journey. In any case, the question was unfortunately tagged w. the interesting "opinion-based" designation! Hopefully someone more experienced with this site can edit the question so that it's compliant.

@AH Well, "But on balance, such shortcoming are indisputably minimized compared to their actual magnitude" is your opinion, which is part of the reason I VTC'd.

@AzorAhai-him- I'm new to this platform but it seems that your decision to VTC was opinion too :-).

I don't deny it, but that is the role of community moderation.

@AH I mean, don't forget that almost everyone mentoring in an academic context is there because they chose an academic path; they're not the most qualified people to advise on other careers because they likely never have had one. They're also heavily filtered by survivorship bias, so their advice even for an academic path is almost as bad as listening to successful entrepreneurs lecture on entrepreneurship.

@BryanKrause Agreed. The real challenge IMO is the lack of recognition of the seriousness of this issue. Take the VTCs to close this topic. As well intentioned as they may be, they're just further (indirect/tangential) evidence of this unfortunate lack of recognition of this important issue.

@AH Eh, I don't know. I think it's taken pretty seriously. Just aren't a lot of good solutions. I wouldn't take question closure as indicating it's not taken seriously, it's closed because this isn't a discussion forum

@BryanKrause: '... their advice even for an academic path is almost as bad as listening to successful entrepreneurs lecture on entrepreneurship.' I'd vote to keep this question around simply to preserve this perfect comment. Nicely done!

40 years ago as a new grad student it was clear to me that I didn’t want to be a professor. Instead I’ve had a pleasant career at a national lab. There are lots of biomedical jobs outside of academia. Only talking about faculty jobs is bad, highlighting the breadth of jobs that graduates have taken is a good step.

I don't agree with your statement "Encouraging students to pursue a career in biomedical research is taken as indisputably the right thing to do". Note, that your link doesn't really support that statement. I totally agree that an academic career with the aim to become a tenured professor is not a rosy one at all. But I disagree that pointing this out  goes against conventional wisdom at all. There are many questions here that discuss exactly this. There are many articles written about this... Yes, maybe this should be discussed even more. No, accepted wisdom does not demand to remain quiet.

Sometimes, I'm conflicted when advising. This can happen for multiple reasons (for example, when I have a personal interest in the matter, etc. )
What always has worked for me is that I don't offer advice. Instead:

I offer facts. Like you did in your question.
Then I point out where the person can get other facts (publications, your network, etc.)
Stop
If asked (frequently), I offer opinions, not advice.
Then, I indicate that my opinion should be taken with a grain of salt.
Finally, point out other people (your network) so they give their thoughts.

